# Javascript single element dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to javascript and have been trying to fathom how to make each element in my code drop down as it is clicked.

At first glance I thought I would need to add $(this). to each of the events but refreshing my page did not affect the behavior, all divs would continue to animate down upon one click.

Here is the script

```
        function slideDiv(elem) {

        if ($(".slidePanel").is(":visible")) {

            $(".contentFade").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "0"
                },

                600,

                function(){
                    $(".slidePanel").slideUp();
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            $(".slidePanel").slideDown(600, function(){
                $(".contentFade").animate(
                    {
                        opacity: "1"
                    },
                    600
                );
            });
        }   
    }
```

I have uploaded the current code here http://jsfiddle.net/alexmk92/z59p8/ so you see the problem I am trying to convey...

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to how to solve this?

Comment: i edited your code just a bit check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those answers are overly complicated....

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400, function() {
        $(this).children('.contentFade').animate({opacity:'1'},400);
    });
})
```

I would suggest adding a class to your a tags that need to do this like `class="toggle"`

Answer (score 0):

i edit your just little bit (about 4-6 lines)

first wrap your `slidePanel` and the link to slide up in some div just a wrapper

```
<div> <!-- new line-->
<a href="#" onclick="slideDiv(this);"> <p class="blueText">A post title here :</p> </a>

<div class="slidePanel">
    <div class="contentFade">
        <p class="p1">Some text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my page</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end contentFade -->
    </div>
    <!-- end sldiePanel -->
    <!-- end post1 -->
</div><!-- new line-->
<div><!-- new line-->
<!-- second post to show issue -->
<a href="#" onclick="slideDiv(this);"> <p class="blueText">A post title here :</p> </a>

<div class="slidePanel">
    <div class="contentFade">
        <p class="p1">Some text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my pageSome text I will be displaying on my page</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end contentFade -->
    </div>
    <!-- end sldiePanel -->
    <!-- end post1 -->
    </div><!-- new line-->
```

then for you js code

```
function slideDiv(elem) {

  if ($(".slidePanel").is(":visible"))//new line
      $(".slidePanel").slideUp();//new line
    if ($(".slidePanel",$(elem).parent()).is(":visible")) {//notice the $(elem).parent()
        $(".contentFade",$(elem).parent()).animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },

            600,

            function(){
                $(".slidePanel",$(elem).parent()).slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $(".slidePanel",$(elem).parent()).slideDown(600, function(){
            $(".contentFade",$(elem).parent()).animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}
```